# Define a response object with an array in YAML using Swagger Editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I'm working on an API definition in Swagger Editor with YAML. I am trying to represent the following response body:

```
{
    success: true,
    ids: [123456, ...]
}
```

and this is what my YAML looks like:

```
definitions:
  SuccessfulResponse:
    type: object 
    properties:
      success:
        type: boolean
        description: True if the all operations were successful
      ids:
        type: array
        items: 
          id: 
          type: string
```

Ive tried several different ways but like this but nothing seems valid

[image]

How do I properly describe the return object that Ive given above?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is an example to define a property as an array of string:

```
  photoUrls:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
```

Ref: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L661-L667

Comment: Both editor options and referenced content has changed and is no longer valid.

Comment: Updated the reference